# Conv2d tensorflow specification

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a binary classifier for grayscale images 129x107 pixels. Here's the model setup, with Conv2d commented out.

```
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(name="MBInput", shape=[129, 107, 1]),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(129,107,1)), # Without this line it all works
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

When I include the convolution step tensorflow complains

`Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 129, 107)`

I'm probably missing something obvious. **What's the right code for 3x3 convolutional filter in this context?**

Comment: You should either resize your input and add another dimension OR remove last dimension (1) from your input.

Comment: @Kaveh - removing ", 1" from shape or input_shape leads to the exact same error.

Comment: Also remove the ``input_shape`` parameter from your dense layer. Would you please add your input data shape? And let me know have you batched your input data?

Comment: I can't be sure because you don't share a sample of your data, but the error is probably because you are feeding your network with 3D data instead of 4D, as grayscale images are usually loaded without a channel dimension.  You might have to manually add a dimension to your input (with `tf.expand_dims` for example). Also, if you specify `input_shape` in your first layer, you don't need to explicitly add an `Input` to your model.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `input_shape` in `Conv2D` layer then there is no need of  explicitly add `Input` layer to the model and don't mix `keras` and `tf.keras`

Working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(129,107,1))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 127, 105, 3)       30        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 40005)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 100)               4000600   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,000,731
Trainable params: 4,000,731
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

If you would like to use `Input` layer, then you can remove `input_shape` from `Conv2D` layer

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(name="MBInput", shape=[129, 107, 1]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=3)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 127, 105, 3)       30        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 40005)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               4000600   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,000,731
Trainable params: 4,000,731
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here both models are same.